# Jquery - cloning a paragraph with no Id

Tags: jquery, dynamic, cloning

```
<div id="note"></div>
<p>
Item 1 
<input name="one" type="checkbox" value="Item 1" />
</p> 
<p>
Item 2 
<input name="two" type="checkbox" value="Item 2" />
</p> 
<p>
Item 3 
<input name="anything" type="checkbox" value="Item 3" />
</p> 
<br/>
Current issue: Does not work as expected. We want to duplicate the paragraph containing the input field whenever it is clicked (involving updating the name). Constraint - Original html cannot be changed.
```

Script (with help from this post)

```
var plen;
$(document).on('click', 'input[type="checkbox"]', function(){
plen = $('p').length
$(this).parent().clone(true).appendTo('body').attr('id',''+plen)
$(this).prop('checked', true);
//alert(plen)
$('#note').text('More of item '+ plen)
});
```

I am getting there but still far from desired result. Explained in JSFiddle.

JSFiddle here : http://jsfiddle.net/Sergelie/ULywc/

Answer (score 0):

Yes we can make clone of the checked parent p tag. Below is the example code.

**HTML**

```
<div id="note"></div>
<p>
Item 1 
<input name="one" type="radio" value="Item 1" />
</p>
```

**jQuery Code**

```
var plen;
$(document).on('change', 'input[type="radio"]', function(){
    plen = $('p').length
    $(this).parent().clone(true).appendTo('body').attr('id','one'+plen)
    $(this).prop('checked', true);
    //alert(plen)
    $('#note').text('More of item '+ plen)
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/yxL8m/1/)

Comment: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/Sergelie/ULywc/)

Rakesh, thanks, we are on the way! I created the jsfiddle closer to the real situation. 

1) If we need a div, it must be created dynamically and be positionned above the clone. 

2) the event should only happen if the box is checked, and be destroyed if the box is unchecked (idealy!)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Sergelie/ULywc/1/ - Where we are right now, I added some comments in the fiddle. Radesh.

Comment: @user3371049 Please update the question with a proper description, instead of commenting new requirements below answers...